# Falcon Framework Response Object: resp.media vs resp.body

Tags: python, response, falconframework

I am unable to understand the key differences and similiarities between response's method: resp.media and resp.body. Are there any guidelines for using one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

[According to official documentation:](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html)

> [**media**](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.media)
>
> object – Returns a deserialized form of the request stream. When
>   called, it will attempt to deserialize the request stream using the
>   Content-Type header as well as the media-type handlers configured via
>   falcon.RequestOptions.
>
> [**body**](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Response.body)
>
> body str or unicode – String representing response content.
>
> If set to a Unicode type (unicode in Python 2, or str in Python 3),
>   Falcon will encode the text as UTF-8 in the response. If the content
>   is already a byte string, use the data attribute instead (it’s
>   faster).